# How to minimize openvpns bandwidth usage?

Tags: openvpn

I'm using openvpn in order to bypass filtering of some sites, I have created my own openvpn server on a linux ubuntu server and using the default config. it works fine but the problem with it is that it uses up much more network traffic than a direct connection. bandwidth is pretty expensive here so I want to know if there are ways to minimize the bandwidth used by openvpn? it doesn't matter if it makes it unsecure or anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every network tunnel (VPN also) makes your bandwith usage larger. It works like that because every packet must be put inside another packet (encapsulation). So in VPN packet some of the protocol headers are included twice - for example there will be one IP header for direct connection and one IP header for the tunneled connection.

And you can't do much with this. But you can try those tips:

- use `proto udp` instead of `proto tcp` (in both server and client configuration files),
- use `dev tun` instead of `dev tap` tunneling (only network layer tunneling, without data link layer tunneling; in both server and client configuration files),
- use compression - in openvpn it is `comp-lzo` directive (must also be on both sides - server and client configuration files).

Comment: can you point how can I set these options?

Comment: I've updated my answer. Those directives you have to change in client and server configuration files (extensions .conf or .ovpn). Declarations of protocol (`proto`) and type of tunnel (`dev tap`) are already in your configuration files, so you need only to change them. The compression is optional so just add it on the end of files.
Check the sample configuration files for more info: https://github.com/OpenVPN/openvpn/blob/master/sample/sample-config-files/server.conf and https://github.com/OpenVPN/openvpn/blob/master/sample/sample-config-files/client.conf .

Comment: I find that it is possible also to change server side settings from the admin interface

Comment: It depends on what kind of additional software you are using